# PHP Exception caught if nothing outputted within try statement.. weird

Tags: php, try-catch, facebook-php-sdk

This is really strange functionality.. and I am not sure if this is something to do with Facebook or PHP.. I would assume the latter..?

My problem is as follows. If a user who has authorized my facebook account visits a page containing the following code, then "hello" is outputted and $me is set.

```
if($user)
{
    try
    {
        $me = $CI->facebook->api('/me');
        $CI->our_fb['is_fb']='YES';
        echo "hello";
    }
        catch(FacebookApiException $e) 
    {               
        echo $e;
    }
}
else
{
    echo "nouser";
}
```

If however a user visits a page, and the code is:

```
if($user)
{
    try
    {
        $me = $CI->facebook->api('/me');
        $CI->our_fb['is_fb']='YES';
        //echo "hello";
    }
        catch(FacebookApiException $e) 
    {               
        echo $e;
    }
}
else
{
    echo "nouser";
}
```

Then "nouser" is outputted.

EDIT

The error is in fact not associated with the try/catch statements but rather the conditional if statements. Apologies.

It seems to be the case that if nothing is outputted within the `if($user)` conditional, then the else statement is being executed. The intention of the conditional is to set a variable not output anything.

Why?

Comment: This question is hard to answer without seeing what exception is thrown. Could you post all details of the exception?

Comment: it has nothing to do with the echo inside, if `nouser` is being outputted then you need to check the value of `$user` in your controller

Comment: User is set directly above. $user=$CI->facebook->getUser(); Given the exact same setup, cleared sessions etc etc. If there is an echo statement within the if conditional, it works, yet if there is not the else statement is executed. Weird behaviour I know..

Answer (score 0):

Please collect more info about the exception using following code:

```
catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getType();    
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Hint:** You are displaying a **blank page** in second example. May be facebook want you to show something in your app (instead of a blank page).

Comment: FUrther details added. Oversight on my part.